# cowbuilder update warns of "Not restarting sysvinit"

Tags: sysvinit

We run a cowbuilder update every morning to grab any updated packages that may have arrived. During this update we are seeing this message sent to stderr:

```
Not restarting sysvinit
```

What does this message mean in the context of a cowbuilder update? Can I safely ignore it?